# How to validate macOS Catalina password dialog? (Has weird icon)

Tags: password, mac-appstore, catalina, dialog

Anyone recognize icon on the App Store download dialog in inline pic below?

On macOS Catalina, I am regularly getting a pop-up requesting I enter my Apple ID and password to download from the App Store.  But I'm concerned because the password prompt dialog doesn't have the App Store app icon, and I don't recognize the icon showing in the upper-left corner of dialog.

I can't think of any other app that might legitimately request the password. When I click the dialog title bar, the foremost running app does not change in the title bar. For example, if it was "Finder" was the forefront app, the menu bar still says "Finder" when I click the dialog title bar, and Safari is the forefront app, the menubar still stays Safari.

I tried googling around for images to discover what the Catalina pop-up *should* look like but I can't find corroborating pics or evidence, and couldn't get a visual conformation. I did notice on older macOS releases that the App Store app icon (the blue icon that looks like an "A") appears in the App Store password prompt dialogs, so not sure why that would change. So this has raised my suspicions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is for "Paste - Clipboard Manager".

I would open the App Store app separate and check the "Updates" tab and the account tab to see if you have indeed requested the download of that app yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I actually figured out which app is doing it from the Activity Monitor. I moved the app to the trash so the update tab of the App Store app certainly shows me no record, but typically do an update all by hand periodically so that could have been it, but why does the app have to update itself from the app store? Anyway, not thrilled about giving any non-Apple app my password, unless macOS is somehow keeping it from the app and simply authenticating access. Unfortunately the process is too obfuscated and I don't use the app enough to keep it.